# If $\int_{\mathbb R} hf=\int_{\mathbb R} gf$ for every probability density $f$, does it follow that $h=f$ a.e.?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> If $\int_{\mathbb R} hf=\int_{\mathbb R} gf$ for any arbitrary probability density $f$, does it follow that $h=f$ a.e.?

It seems to be right for that taking f as an indicator function over $[-n,n]$ divided by $2n$ will show that $h=g$ almost everywhere on $[-n,n]$ for each $n$. I just wanted to double check that this is a valid argument.

Comment: @Ian No, the OP's method doesn't work as is because with $h(x)=x$, $g(x)=0$, for the constructed $f$ sequence you have $\int hf=\int gf$, yet $h\ne g$. You need to consider more kinds of PDF functions.

Comment: Ah yes, you would need nonnegativity in this case, thanks.

Comment: I edited your question. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll use the theorem that says that if $f>0$ on a set $A$ of positive measure, then $\int_A f>0$.

Clearly by considering $h-g$ we can reduce the original claim to

> If $g$ is a Lebesgue measurable real function such that $\int gf=0$ for any PDF $f$ (i.e. a nonnegative function with $\int f=1$), then $g=0$ almost everywhere.

Let $A^+$ be the set of points for which $g(x)>0$, and $A^-$ for the set of points with $g(x)<0$. If $m(A^+)+m(A^-)=0$, then $g=0$ a.e. and we are done, and otherwise either $m(A^+)$ or $m(A^-)$ is positive, and by taking $-g$ in place of $g$ we can assume that $m(A^+)>0$.

But then the theorem I mentioned at the beginning implies that $\int_{A^+}g>0$, so $\int_{A^+}g\cdot\frac1{m(A^+)}>0$, and by taking $f(x)=\frac1{m(A^+)}$ on $A^+$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, you have a contradiction to the hypothesis.

We can also extend the theorem to complex valued $g,h$ by applying the above separately to the real and imaginary parts of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using indicator functions of intervals is a good idea.

Making them wide and flat is a bad idea. Do the opposite: use tall skinny functions.

By the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$ we have 
$$
f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \phi_r(x)\,dx
$$
where $\phi_r(x) = \frac{1}{2r}\chi_{[x-r,x+r]}$ is a probability density function (uniform distribution on $[x-r,x+r]$). Thus, integrals of the form $ \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \phi_r(x)\,dx$ determine $f$ almost everywhere.